# Sending a mail with net/smtp through http CONNECT proxy

Tags: go, proxy, smtp

My Go program sends a mail with the `net/smtp` library.

```
        client, err := smtp.Dial(addr)
```

When connecting to the SMTP server I would like to pass through a HTTP CONNECT-based proxy.

Comment: Do you mean like a SOCKS proxy ? You won't be able to send SMTP traffic over a HTTP proxy, it's not HTTP ?

Comment: Yes like a SOCKS proxy. By using the HTTP  connect method (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) the same way HTTPS traffic is done through HTTP proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send SMTP traffic via a CONNECT proxy, you'll need to make use of `smtp.NewClient(conn net.Conn, host string)` with an existing connection (`net.Conn`) to your CONNECT proxy.

The [`magisterquis/connectproxy`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/magisterquis/connectproxy) package is most likely be what you will need to create this connection:

```golang
d, err := connectproxy.New("https://proxyserver:4433", proxy.Direct)
if nil != err{
     panic(err)
}

c, err := d.Dial("tcp", "upstream.mail.server:25")
if nil != err {
     panic(err)
}

smtpClient, err := smtp.NewClient(c, "upstream.mail.server")
if nil != err {
     panic(err)
}
```